# Java run command not opening

Tags: java

I had installed Java to work with Android Studio. Java works fine on Android Studio but when I try to use Java run command on my computer, it opens and closes immediately. How do I run Java on my computer?

Comment: If you try running the command inside a command shell or terminal window (depending on your OS) you should be able to see what error or message is displayed.

Comment: Open cmd.exe and then run your command.

Comment: how does it relate to Android?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command window (cmd on Windows)
2. Type java -version
   You should see the installed java version output.

Answer (score 0):

u need to add this path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin wheres javac.exe locate copy the path 
1. go to System properties then click on advanced system setting .
2. click on Environment variables as picture describe
3. choose the path from system variables and edit it
4. go to end of the line and important to separate between variable values before paste javac.exe path make sure to put semi-colon and paste the path

[image: click on Environment variables as picture describe]
[image: choose the path from system variables and edit it]
[image: go to end of the line and important to separate between variable values before paste javac.exe path make sure to put semi-colon and paste the path]

Comment: User is not asking **how to setup java path variable**, instead the issue is :cmd is closing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you have the following Registry setting configured:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System!DisableCMD
```

If you see the value '`DisableCMD`' in the above location then simply `delete` it.

If you are not comfortable with editing the Registry then you will find this setting by going to:

```
Start > RUN
```

Type `gpedit.msc` and press `OK`

Navigate to: `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System` 
Look for the option '`Prevent access to the command prompt`' 
Double click it and choose '`Not Configured`'